# Build errors when running gatsby build after using getServerData() for SSR page

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, server-side-rendering

My site builds fine initially, but when trying to create a page that's SSR using **getServerData** while using gatsby-source-wordpress i get the following:

```
 ERROR #98001  ENGINE.VALIDATION
 Built Rendering Engines failed validation.
 
 Error, when running gatsby build.
```

When setting the silent bool to false in Gatsby's validate engines util I get the following:

```
gatsby-source-wordpress  diff schemas
Validating Rendering Engines
error Error: [Immer] minified error nr: 18 'MapSet'. Find the full error at...
```

Gatsby build runs fine using the **getServerData** function, it's only when using it in-conjunction with gatsby-source-wordpress.

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^5.3.2",
    "gatsby-adapter-netlify": "^1.1.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-alias-imports": "^1.0.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^3.13.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^5.3.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify": "^5.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^6.3.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^6.3.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^6.13.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^5.13.1",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^5.13.1",
    "gatsby-source-wordpress": "^7.13.3",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^5.13.1",
    "html-react-parser": "^5.1.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "postcss": "^8.2.10",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "typeface-merriweather": "1.1.13",
    "typeface-montserrat": "1.1.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dumper.js": "^1.3.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "prettier": "3.2.5"
  }
```

Ssr page:

```
import * as React from "react"
import { getPreviewPage } from "@api/preview"

    const Preview = ({ serverData }) => (
      <main>
        <h1>SSR page</h1>
        <h2>Page title: {serverData.title}</h2>
      </main>
    )
    
    export default Preview
    
    export async function getServerData({ query }) {
      const page = await getPreviewPage(query.id)
    
      return {
        props: page,
      }
    }
```

Build log:

```
success onPreBootstrap - 3.054s
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  ensuring plugin requirements are met - 0.027s
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  diff schemas - 2.220s
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  ingest WPGraphQL schema - 2.336s
success createSchemaCustomization - 2.392s
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  pull updates since last build - 0.870s
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  fetch root fields - 1.042s
success Clean up stale nodes - 0.007s - 10/0 0.00/s
success Checking for changed pages - 0.000s
success source and transform nodes - 1.150s
info Writing GraphQL type definitions to /Users/Matt/Documents/Workspace/Menabrea/menabrea-site/.cache/schema.gql
success building schema - 0.360s
success createPages - 0.065s
success createPagesStatefully - 0.038s
info Total nodes: 113, SitePage nodes: 10 (use --verbose for breakdown)
success Checking for changed pages - 0.001s
success Cleaning up stale page-data - 0.003s
success onPreExtractQueries - 0.001s
success extract queries from components - 1.392s
success write out redirect data - 0.001s
success Build manifest and related icons - 0.090s
success onPostBootstrap - 0.093s
info bootstrap finished - 53.544s
success write out requires - 0.004s
success Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles - 0.641s
⠦ Building Rendering Engines
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (123kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (123kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (123kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffe
⠇ Building Rendering Engines
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (835kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (835kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (835kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffe
success Building Rendering Engines - 2.198s
success Building HTML renderer - 1.089s
success Execute page configs - 0.208s
⠼  gatsby-source-wordpress  ingest WPGraphQL schema
⠸  gatsby-source-wordpress  diff schemas
⠼ Validating Rendering Engines
error Error: [Immer] minified error nr: 18 'MapSet'. Find the full error at: ...
    at n (/Users/Matt/Documents/Workspace/Menabrea/menabrea-site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:296280:121)
    at b (/Users/Matt/Documents/Workspace/Menabrea/menabrea-site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:296280:1962)
    at N (/Users/Matt/Documents/Workspace/Menabrea/menabrea-site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:296280:3448)
    at Object.get (/Users/Matt/Documents/Workspace/Menabrea/menabrea-site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:296280:14315)
    at Object.setState [as remoteSchema/setState] (/Users/Matt/Documents/Workspace/Menabrea/menabrea-site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:296404:7)
    at combinedReducer (/Users/Matt/Documents/Workspace/Menabrea/menabrea-site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:295890:40)
    at /Users/Matt/Documents/Workspace/Menabrea/menabrea-site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:296229:14
    at produce (/Users/Matt/Documents/Workspace/Menabrea/menabrea-site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:296280:15938)
    at /Users/Matt/Documents/Workspace/Menabrea/menabrea-site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:296228:61
    at combination (/Users/Matt/Documents/Workspace/Menabrea/menabrea-site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:34586:29)
    at dispatch (/Users/Matt/Documents/Workspace/Menabrea/menabrea-site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:34326:22)
    at Object.dispatch (/Users/Matt/Documents/Workspace/Menabrea/menabrea-site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:296111:16)
    at Object.assign.isEffect [as setState] (/Users/Matt/Documents/Workspace/Menabrea/menabrea-site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:296007:20)
    at checkIfSchemaHasChanged (/Users/Matt/Documents/Workspace/Menabrea/menabrea-site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:401709:48)
    at runSteps (/Users/Matt/Documents/Workspace/Menabrea/menabrea-site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:293732:9)
    at ingestRemoteSchema (/Users/Matt/Documents/Workspace/Menabrea/menabrea-site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:401578:5)
error  gatsby-source-wordpress  
⠼  gatsby-source-wordpress  ingest WPGraphQL schema
⠼  gatsby-source-wordpress  diff schemas
failed Validating Rendering Engines - 2.916s

 ERROR #98001  ENGINE.VALIDATION

Built Rendering Engines failed validation.

Please open an issue with a reproduction at https://gatsby.dev/new-issue for more help.



  Error: Worker exited before finishing task
  
  - index.js:205 ChildProcess.<anonymous>
    [menabrea-site]/[gatsby-worker]/dist/index.js:205:41
  

not finished  gatsby-source-wordpress  ingest WPGraphQL schema - 0.429s
not finished  gatsby-source-wordpress  diff schemas - 0.426s
```

Running gatsby develop works fine it's only when running the build cmd.

Comment: This seems to be an issue when using gatsby-source-wordpress, why? I have no idea, really frustrating.

Comment: We're going to need to have more information to help you with this. You mention that the problem might be to do with `gatsby-source-wordpress`. Can you help me understand how you came to this conclusion? It's not apparent from your original question which doesn't mention this package. Might also be helpful to include the following in your question: (1) overall project layout (output from `tree`), (2) contents of your `package.json` and (3) the contents of `preview.js`. With that information I'm sure we can sort this out!

Comment: Hey @datawookie, updated my description, would be great if you could help :) cheers!

Comment: Thanks for providing that. When I build a test project using the information you have provided I run into an error for the line `import { getPreviewPage } from "@api/preview"`. Presumably this import refers to a file that is internal to your project. When I comment out that line the build works fine. Is the contents of the imported package where the problem lies? Without more information I cannot replicate this issue. Sorry. Can you strip your project down to a **minimal** reproducible example and then share everything that's needed to get the error?

Comment: @datawookie that's right, getPreviewPage is a fetch method from another file. So you were able to run a gatsby build with gatsby-source-wordpress in your project and having a getServerData function?

Instead of importing the getPreviewPage you could just throw in this to test the getServerData function:

export async function getServerData() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random`)

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Response failed`)
    }

    return {
      props: await res.json(),
    }
  }
}

Comment: That's what I have in my function. You can see the source here: https://gitlab.com/datawookie/gatsby-whimsyweb/-/blob/0-starter/src/pages/using-ssr.js?ref_type=heads. If you want help please provide a minimal example that can be used to replicate your problem. You can simply create a GitHub repository for the code and share it while we resolve the issue. Then we document the solution here and you delete the repository. However, if I can't replicate then problem then I'm not clever enough to help.

Comment: Will do, in the meantime, if you try installing gatsby-source-wordpress and hooking that up, try run a build and see what happens? my build works too without gatsby-source-wordpress, which is how i narrowed down the issue to that.

Will create a repo soon, appreciating your help @datawookie

Comment: When I add `gatsby-source-wordpress` to my test project it builds fine. Please share your repo ASAP.

Comment: Hmm strange, here is my repo @datawookie https://github.com/Mellis84/gatsby-wordpress-ssr

I'm getting more issues now after i removed the node_modules folder and package.lock and npm installing again...

Comment: Thanks! However it would be better if you shared code that's consistent with your question. You mention that "gatsby develop works fine" but I'm not sure. When I try to run a development server I get an error: "getPosts is not defined". Checking `gatsby-node.js` I see that the `require()` statements at the top of the file have been commented. Can you please push a current version of the project that works in development mode? Then we should be able to easily figure out the issue with a build.